# Populating an HTML table in QGIS print layout with data from multiple layers using Atlas coverage layer

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-atlas

I am working on a QGIS print layout where I need to populate an HTML table with data from different layers. I have set up an Atlas coverage layer and I'm using `@atlas_featureid` as a filter to retrieve the required attribute values. However, I'm facing an issue where the get_feature() function only retrieves the first feature, and I need to retrieve multiple features based on a condition.

I would like to achieve something similar to the code below, but it's not working as I cannot use `attribute(get_feature()) = something` as a condition, at least as far as I understand.

```sql
CASE
WHEN attribute(get_feature('Qg_Projet', 'qgPrj_kAffaire', @atlas_featureid), 'qgPrj_knMetier') = 2 
THEN attribute(get_feature('Qg_Projet', 'qgPrj_kAffaire', @atlas_featureid  ), 'qgPrj_iAnneeSouhaitee')
ELSE '-'
END
```

Comment: Are you able to share some sample data?